# SQL multiple CTEs but no results

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a table *TrainingCredits* of EmployeeIDs with their credits for training hours earned:
** EmpID, CourseNum, Credits, CompletedDate**
151, 400, 0.5, 10/1/2022

Each course has separate table *Courses* with tags for content area:
**CourseNum, CourseName, Creditspossible, Tags**  CourseNum is unique
400, Javascript 101, 3.0, JSC

With **Tags **being a 3 letter code (*JSC, PRL, SQL*) with multiples allowed and comma-separated.

I need to summarize for each employee the total credits earned for each tag.

For a singular query, I have:

```
SELECT
    EmpID,
    sum(Credits)
FROM TrainingCredits
INNER JOIN courses on TrainingCredits.courseNum=courses.courseNum
WHERE
        courses.tag LIKE '%JSC%' 
        GROUP BY EmpID
```

That works for the single Tag type JSC. To repeat it for each Tag type, i just need to change the "Courses.tag LIKE '%PRL%'" line and run it again.

I tried creating a CTE for each tag type:

```
WITH JSCCreds (CEmpID, JSCcred) AS ( 
    SELECT                            //* this SELECT repeats for each below ...  *//
        EmpID,
        sum(Credits)
    FROM TrainingCredits
        INNER JOIN courses on TrainingCredits.courseNum=courses.CourseNum
    WHERE
                Courses.Tag LIKE '%JSC%' 
        GROUP BY TrainingCredits.EmpID  ),
PRLCreds (PEmpID, PRLCred) As (
...
                Courses.Tag LIKE '%PRL%' ),
SQLCreds (SEmpID, SQLcred) AS (
...
                Courses.Tag LIKE '%SQL%' )
...
SELECT EmpID,
    JSCCreds.JSCcred,
    PRLCreds.PRLcred,
    SQLCreds.SQLcred
FROM TrainingCredits
WHERE
        TrainingCredits.EmpID=JSCCreds.JEmpID
    AND TrainingCredits.EmpID=PRLCreds.PEmpID
    AND TrainingCredits.EmpID=SQLCreds.SEmpID
```

But that is not giving me any results. I was expecting a list of EmpID with totals for each tag type.

I suspect my error is in the CTE data, but I'm no expert (this is about my skill level with SQL).

Is there a better way of doing this? I have thought of changing the single CSV tag type to a separate Boolean field for each Tag (Courses.JSCtag=true, Courses.PRLtag=false, Courses.SQLtag=False for example). But before I take that on, I'd rather get some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: You defined all those CTEs but then you never use the in the main select.  You have to join or union them to get their data

Comment: Why not GROUP BY the EmpID and Tag in a single query and then PIVOT the result?

Comment: My SQL skills are advanced beginner (if that). CTEs are something I just learned about, so knowing how to use them is a matter of learning that. Now that Kurt pointed out my mistake.... PIVOT I know a bit from Excel, but I'll look into that NickW.

Comment: Thanks. Kurt. SInce most of my data was already configured, some joining worked to get the results needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say what version of SQL you are using. I did this in SQL Server.

First - test data... 2 employees, 4 classes, all tags (notice employee 151 has two sql classes (410 and 412)).
[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vRnJnAO_)

```
CREATE TABLE trainingCredits (EmpID INT, CourseNum INT, Credits Decimal(10,2), CompletedDate DATE)
INSERT INTO trainingCredits
VALUES
  (151, 400, 0.5, '10/1/2022')
, (151, 410, 1, '11/15/2022')
, (151, 412, 2, '11/15/22')
, (151, 430, 1, '10/12/23')
, (155, 400, 0.5, '10/1/2022') 

CREATE TABLE courses (courseNum INT, courseName NVARCHAR(50), CreditsPossible DECIMAL(10,2), Tags NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO courses
VALUES
  (400, 'Javascript 101', 3.0, 'JSC')
, (410, 'SQL 101', 3.0, 'SQL')
, (412, 'Expressions matter more than statements', 2.5, 'SQL')
, (430, 'PRL stands for something?', 16, 'PRL')
```

To get your sums, I summed partitioned by employee and tags.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
       EmpID
     , c.Tags
     , SUM(Credits) OVER (PARTITION BY t.EmpID, c.Tags ORDER BY t.empID) Credits
  FROM trainingCredits t
  JOIN courses c ON t.CourseNum = c.CourseNum
```

In the comments NickW suggested pivoting the result which is not a bad idea but currently, this query returns:

| EmpID | Tags | Credits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 151 | JSC | 0.50 |
| 151 | PRL | 1.00 |
| 151 | SQL | 3.00 |
| 155 | JSC | 0.50 |

Comment: Sorry. this is Oracle.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that had to be simpler.

Comment: The complicating factor is that I can't set up my data the way described since it comes from a table that I can't access easily, and I cannot make changes to it. So I can only have a single tag field per course (I was not clear on that in OP, my apologies). So for a course with multiple tags, the tag field is like "JSC, SQL, PRL" instead of having a single course_number with multiple tag records as described.  I think I could create a CTE for all courses and split out the multiple tags, then use that as the partition as described.